# Sending contents of chatbot to specific people

Tags: twilio, bots, sms, chatbot

Wondering if you can help please, I am evaluating a few products for a project I am working on and curious to know if you would recommend Twilio or any other communication platform for this?

For background, this is a project to help a friend. They are not a developer so keen to build on a platform that can be easily managed.

I am building a voice and SMS chatbot. The idea is a user can contact the bot, they will be asked to enter a specific code (think table number) then answer the questions the bot asks.

Depending on the code entered the answers of the bot will be sent to specific person (waiter).

EG:

- Code 111 - send responses to Adam
- Code 112 - send responses to Ben
- Code 113 - send responses to Chris

The problem is, there could be hundreds of waiters, so they are not operators in the sense of a call center, they may come and go as well so it needs to be easy to manage.

So the question is, what platform would you recommend for something like this? I have some experience with Twilio, although I've only hooked up the API, haven't used their other products.

**TDLR:** *I want to find a platform to build a quick project that sends the details of a chatbot to a specific person that can be identified by a code the chatbot asks.*

Answer (score 0):

Twilio is powering the underlying backend API's, so what makes the "experience" for your friend is how you design the front-end.

From a Twilio perspective, all of the use cases you provided plus more are very common and well documented in the product documentation and [blogs](https://blog.twilio.com/), so from a developer standpoint (you), it comes down to how easy it is to understand the underlying API's (and SDKs) and the greater developer community ecosystem.